# Cassandra CQL prepared statements slower than non prepared ones?

Tags: performance, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Lately we've been stress testing some of our Cassandra clusters comparing performance of all combinations of consistency leves, prepared/non-prepared statements and sync/async execution modes and on every single configuration the highest performance has always been the combination of (any/one) non-prepared statements running asynchronously!!

There are to bits meaningful there, any/one consistency levels are the less restrictive, so should be fastest therefore. Also running queries asynchronously, and therefore taking advantage of parallel computation should be, and is, faster than running them sequentially, but what about the prepared vs non-prepared statement?

We've always read and heard (blogs, summits, evangelists, ...) that we should favor prepared statements over non prepared whenever possible, but this results are confusing...

To give you a bit of background we've used two different tools (one internally built and cassandra-stress) both throwing the same results.

Has anyone come across this before? Which is the explanation? What are we missing?

Regards

Edit:

- [Results using cassandra-stress tool](https://gist.github.com/calonso/99878f5495a51e68037e)
- [Results using our own Ruby script](https://gist.github.com/calonso/43ea2c5e7a61f831a86c)

Comment: Are you preparing every time you make a query, or just once?   If doing just once you should save some time, but I've seen in traces with Cassandra that it saves microseconds of time (as unprepared queries need to be prepared on the cassandra end).  It should save on the amount of data that goes over the wire since the column definitions are known on both sides once you've prepared the query.

Comment: Hey @AndyTolbert thanks for your comment. Yes, I'm preparing the statement just once. Also the prepared statement should save the statement parsing on Cassandra end for subsequent executions of that same statement. From my understanding prepared statements save in network (statements execution only submit the bound values) and in parsing (the statement is parsed by the engine only once). That's what it makes this situation so weird!

Comment: Some details would be really helpful. Namely: What language driver. Sample query? Size of your cluster and RF for the keyspace. Data model if you can.

Comment: Hi @PatrickMcFadin Thanks for your reply!! I've just edited the post with a gist where I share results using cassandra-stress tool. I'll add another with the results of our own benchmarks (Ruby) right now.

Comment: The cluster here is a 3 node cluster in a VPC on EC2, 1 node in each AZ. DSE 4.6, C* 2.0.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking over your data, I think what you are seeing here is a limit not on your cluster, but on the server running the test. If you are testing a 3 node Cassandra cluster, you may need 2-3 times the amount of client servers producing the load. You can try to maximize the amount of use on each client by increasing the number of threads, but you'll hit a limit.

Just in general, if you are getting a flat line result on a cassandra-stress test, look at the nodes under test. If they are mostly bored, increase the number of clients(or threads) until the nodes are, well, stressed. :)

Comment: Hey @PatrickMcFadin,
Thank you very much for your reply and sorry for the delay in coming back, we've been stressing the cluster with 3 clients simultaneously and now the results are more meaningful.
We see less operations per client but a higher overall and also, prepared statements are performing slightly better (I was expecting more difference) than non prepared ones.
Conclusion: Prepared statements are like relational DB indexes, useless if not enough load?
Gists with the results: https://gist.github.com/calonso/e23dfadda3e9a5cca016 and https://gist.github.com/calonso/ea8323e953648fed0541

Comment: Exactly right. They are meant to shave off precious milliseconds when it counts. Under a high load, it can really make a difference as seen here by a study Netflix did. http://techblog.netflix.com/2013/12/astyanax-update.html